# Conley index as a subset of an isolated invariant set

Tags: algebraic-topology, dynamical-systems, homotopy-theory, morse-theory

In Sec. 7 (p. 60) of Conley's $\textit{Isolated Invariant Sets and the Morse Index (1976)}$, the following passage appears:

> (In fact any isolated invariant set in $S$ is isolated in $\Phi$. It seems there ought to be some way to say the index of $S'$ in $S$ is "greater than" its index in $\Phi$: **obviously if the index in $S$ is $\bar{0}$ the index in $\Phi$ is also**. Since there is more room to move around in $\Phi$, the latter index cannot imply as much about $S'$ as the former. Note that if $S'$ is isolated in $S$ and $\Phi$ is the product of $S$ with the flow in $\mathbb{R}^1$ defined by $dx/dt=x$, then the index of $S'$ in $\Phi$ is the suspension of its index in $S$; thus the suspension of $X$ should be "less than" $X$. So far as this author knows such questions have not been studied in this context.)

I'm a little confused generally about this passage, but I have been struggling specifically to understand the bold portion. Since Conley says it is obvious, it probably is, but not yet to me. **My question:** Why is the bold “obvious” sentence true?

**Notes on the passage.** $S'$ is an isolated invariant subset of the isolated invariant set $S$. $\Phi$ is what Conley calls a "local flow" which for him is roughly a state space together with a local flow *map* $\varphi^t$ defined for small times $t$, although often Conley simply refers to the state space alone by $\Phi$. I believe the indices referred to above are the *homotopy* Conley indices $h(S',S)$ and $h(S',\Phi)$ (Conley's notation) rather than the indices $I(S',S)$ and $I(S',\Phi)$ as connected simple systems (p. 51 of the text). For a definition of isolated invariant sets and the homotopy Conley index, I refer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118574/conley-index-for-isolated-invariant-sets-with-no-exit-points).

Comment: Roughly: if a homotopy has more freedom, then it cannot increase, only decrease or stay the same. He does write "there is more room to move around in $\Phi$".

Comment: @JohnB that seems vaguely intuitive to me, but when I try to pin it down I don't really know what it means: e.g. is the homotopy type of a torus "less than" the homotopy type of sphere? Why does that question make any sense? More specifically: I still can't figure out how to actually prove the bold statement involving $\bar{0}$.

Comment: You should ask Conley why he decided to be vague. :) Seriously: it doesn't make sense to compare the torus and the sphere (unless you take a double covering with four ramification points), but in Conley's paper it is the trivial situation of **inclusion**, it is unrelated to what you mention. There is nothing else to it, as mostly with Conley index.

Comment: @JohnB fair enough :). Hmm. Would you mind (at least sketching) a proof of the bold statement involving $\bar{0}$ if it is clear to you?